# Comment relancer poliment un forum suite à une demande ?

Tags: expressions, politesse, correspondance

Je me suis inscrit dans un forum mais récemment j'ai demandé le changement de mon pseudo et ils m'ont dit :

« L'admin est prévenu et fera le nécessaire dès que possible. »

Je lui ai répondu : « d'accord merci beaucoup ».

Mais ça fait plus de dix jours que la procédure de changement de pseudo a été commencée ; je sais bien que ça va prendre du temps mais ma question est : comment puis-je peux les rappeler gentiment c'est-à-dire par une formule de politesse ?

Est-ce que par exemple je peux dire :

> Bonjour, Permettez moi de vous rappeler de prendre mon changement de pseudo en considération

Comment: Une simple clarification : si j'ai bien compris, le but est de savoir comment formuler une relance polie. « [Formule de politesse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/formule_de_politesse) » désigne généralement la formule qui début ou clôt le message. Il est par ailleurs possible d'utiliser des formules de politesse sans être particulièrement poli (par sarcasme par exemple, ou simplement parce qu'on oublie que la politesse doit transcrire un certain respect de l'interlocuteur). La question ne porte donc ici pas tant sur les formules de politesse que sur la politesse tout court.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tout d'abord, la formule n'est pas vraiment polie dans le sens que l'on rappelle les devoirs de la personne. Elle pourrait interpréter cela comme « vous faites mal votre travail », ce qui n'est pas l'effet voulu.

Il serait plus judicieux de demander l'état de la demande, comme par exemple :

> Bonjour,
>
> Je me permets de vous contacter car j'aimerais savoir où en est ma demande de changement de pseudo sur le forum.
>
> Cordialement,
>
> "mon pseudo du forum"

Comment: SVP dans la signature est ce que je met  mon pseudo du forum  actuelle  ou bien le nouveau que je desire

Comment: @Educ Une solution est de mettre les deux, par exemple « AncienPseudo/NouveauPseudo ». Il faut laisser figurer le pseudo actuel afin que les admins puissent retrouver facilement la demande en question, et même si le nouveau pseudo définit votre identité actuelle.